# Generate Matlab plot in 2014b using 2014a graphics suite

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-hg2

Due to a recent update to 2014b we have seen some detrimental effects to some very custom designed graphs, they are virtually unreadable now and it is of the belief that the new 2014b suite has caused this.

Is there any way to plot using the old 2014a engine? This is only a temporary fix, but at the moment time cannot be dedicated to redesigning the script.

If there was some function like:

```
gca 2014a
```

That associated the current handle with the old engine this would save lives here. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: While they are not completely compatible, the new engine is just better than the old. You wont need much change to get the code work for the new  engine, and it will be worth the effort. Additionally, the future versions from now on are going to be with the new engine, so in general: "adapt to survive!"

Comment: @AnderBiguri Oh I definitely agree about the adaptation, but if you saw these graphs you would agree this is going to take a bit longer than you would hope! Since Matlab 2014a is still installed on the computer it may just be easier to run the script using that for now and work on it in the meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to get you started:

You can get back to the old colormap by changing it to `jet`.

You can convert back to numeric handles by converting it to a double (note I have never user this feature in practice):

```
hFig = double(hFig);
```